# Sphinx auto-documentation doesn't work with classes which improt other classes

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I am currently working on a python project and want to automatically generate the documentation for my project

In order to automatically generate my documentation, I do:

1. `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source ../modules`
2. `make html`

But when I do that, I get the following error:
`WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'CalculationManager' from module 'model'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'modules'`

I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone help me?

My `folder structure` of the project:
[image]

The `CalculationManager` class:

```py
from modules.model import CalculationPhase
from modules.model import ConfigurationManager


class CalculationManager:
    """
    The CalculationManager manages Calculation of the Project.
    """

    def __init__(self, starting_point: CalculationPhase, configuration_manager: ConfigurationManager):
        """
        Gets called when we first create an object of this class, it saves all information it needs for
        starting a calculation.

        Args:
            starting_point: Describes in which calculation-phase we want to start the calculation.
            configuration_manager: Saves all information required to configure the calculation.
        """
        pass

    def cancel_calculation(self):
        """
        This method is used when we want to cancel an ongoing calculation.
        """
        pass

    def _validate_starting_point(self) -> bool:
        """
        Validates the correctness of the Staring Point.

        Returns:
            bool: If true then the starting_point is valid, this means every calculation up to this point exist
            and are saved in the project.
        """
        pass

    def _start_calculation(self):
        """
        Starts the calculation.
        """
        pass
```

The other classes in the folder modules are empty, they have a class and pass standing in it.

My `index.rst`:

```
.. ExampleProject documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Mon Dec 19 19:53:45 2022.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to ExampleProject's documentation!
==========================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
    
   modules

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

My `conf.py`:

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../modules/'))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'x'
copyright = 'x'
author = 'x'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '1.0.0'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon' # support for google docstring style
]

autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
    'member-order': 'bysource',
    'special-members': '__init__',
    'undoc-members': True,
    'exclude-members': '__weakref__'
}

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'sphinx_book_theme'
# html_logo = "../../../pictures/"

html_theme_options = {
    # "external_links": [],
    "repository_url": "https://github.com/LuposX/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten",
    "repository_branch": "main",
    "path_to_docs": "pythoncode/docs/",
    "use_repository_button": True,
}


# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
# html_static_path = ['_static']
```

The html site:
[image]

You can see that `model.CalculationManager module`is empty.

Full `make html` description:
[image]
**EDIT1**:

- Misspelled init, wasn't the problem though
- Added full sphinx build log

**EDIT2:**
Someone recommended to add `__init__.py` to the modules folder, I tried this already if I do this I get a circular dependency Issue, look below:

```bash
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
loading pickled environment... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst, modules.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 3 added, 1 changed, 3 removed
reading sources... [100%] modules.view                                                                                                 
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst:4: WARNING: duplicated entry found in toctree: modules
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'control' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.CalculationManager' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.CalculationPhase' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.ConfigurationManager' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'view' from module 'modules'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'modules'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.control.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.model.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.view.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... /home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: self referenced toctree found. Ignored.
done
writing output... [100%] modules.view                                                                                                  
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
/home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
generating indices... genindex /home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
done
writing additional pages... search /home/lupos/Documents/KonfiguratorFuerOSMDaten/pythoncode/docs/source/modules.rst: WARNING: circular toctree references detected, ignoring: modules <- modules
done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 20 warnings.

The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

**EDIT3**:
The problem was the name of my `modules` folder had the same name as the automatically generated `.rst` file, so it self referenced itself.
After fixing it, I get now the following error:

```
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
loading pickled environment... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst, modules.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 4 added, 1 changed, 3 removed
reading sources... [100%] modules                                                                                                               
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'control' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.CalculationManager' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.CalculationPhase' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model.ConfigurationManager' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'model' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'view' from module 'ConfiguratorOSMData'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'ConfiguratorOSMData'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] modules                                                                                                                
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 7 warnings.

The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

The folder structure now looks like this:
[image]

**EDIT4**:
I changed the folder structure to:
[image]

And added in `conf.py`:
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', 'src')))`

Which fixed the erros, but now the html looks weird:
[image]

It shows the whole path to the classes. How do i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it should be `__int__`?

Comment: @KlausD. what do you mean? can you specify?

Comment: Search this page for that string!

Comment: I don't get what you mean, __init__ is how you do a constructor in python and in this class I need a constructor. If you refer to the pydoc placement below the method header of init instead of above, thats the google code style.

Comment: Yes,  `__init__` is a constructor, but you misspelled it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good catch. I can't believe neither me nor my IDE saw that. The problem still persists, though.

Comment: `modules` needs an `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: @StevePiercy I tried that, but it made everything worse, I get a circular dependency issue. See new edit

Answer (score 0):

nvm it works, solved the last problem by insertin in `conf.py`:
`autodoc_typehints = "description"`